# Should I check if a user exists before deleting it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I saw many times code like this:

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
var result = await _userManager.DeleteAsync(user);

return new JsonResult(result);
```

But I would like to know your opinion if this is good or is better to do if statement where you check if user really exist or not?

Answer (score 2):

That depends upon `_userManager.DeleteAsync` implementation, since you are using .Net Core Identity, implementation of `DeleteAsync` method will throw `ArgumentNullException`

You can check source code [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/a273e349eea2be3a40b16e6947b2deab95f4b5b2/src/Core/UserManager.cs#L5120), and here is method's implementation:

```
public virtual Task<IdentityResult> DeleteAsync(TUser user)
    {
        ThrowIfDisposed();
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
        }

        return Store.DeleteAsync(user, CancellationToken);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on the context in which the deletion is performed:

- If your program is in an active interaction with an end-user who requests user deletion, then knowing that the user he wanted to delete did not exist is a valuable piece of information, so you should report it.
- If your program executes a batch clean-up of some sort, and the situation when a user may or may not exist is fine, then you could skip the check.

**Note** your code would end up checking `user` for `null` anyway to avoid `ArgumentNullException` in the call of `DeleteAsync`. That's only an implementation detail: the real decision that you need to make is what to do about it.

Answer (score -1):

*Note: this answer assumes you are using the built-in `UserManager` and not a custom one.*

As you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/a273e349eea2be3a40b16e6947b2deab95f4b5b2/src/Core/UserManager.cs#L512):

```
public virtual Task<IdentityResult> DeleteAsync(TUser user)
{
    ThrowIfDisposed();
    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
    }

    return Store.DeleteAsync(user, CancellationToken);
}
```

Passing `null` as a parameter to `DeleteAsync` would throw an `ArgumentNullException`. So, no, the code you provided is not correct. You need to check whether the user exists in the first place:

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);

if (user == null)
{
    return BadRequest("User not found");
}

var result = await _userManager.DeleteAsync(user);

return Json(result);
```

Comment: @Nyerguds Why would you catch an exception you have absolutely no need to get thrown? Exceptions are expensive

Comment: Not really. Compared to database calls, that expense is completely negligible.